# Complete Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

> The complete elliptic integral of the second kind is defined by $$E(k)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}~d\theta,0\leq k\leq1$$ For all $0\leq k\leq1$ show that $\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-k^2}\leq E(k)\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

I'm having trouble with this question :( We just started learning about the fundamental theorem of calculus, and what I've been finding elsewhere online seems to be much more complex than what I know myself. I was told to set up parameters $M$ and $m$ to "squeeze" the function into an inequality but I'm unsure what to do next or how that even works in the first place. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Think about the surface between the curve and the $x$ axis (the curve being always above the axis).

As marty cohen answered, for any value of $\theta$ you have $$0 \le 1-k^2 \le  1-k^2\sin^2 \theta \le 1$$ So $$0 \le \sqrt{1-k^2} \le \sqrt{ 1-k^2\sin^2 \theta} \le 1$$  So $$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{1-k^2}\,d\theta\le\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{ 1-k^2\sin^2 \theta}\,d\theta\le\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}d\theta$$ The first and third integrals are simple, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

$1-k^2 \le  1-k^2\sin^2 \theta \le 1
$

You can get
a better upper bound with
$\sqrt{1-z} 
\le 1-z/2
$,
so
$\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \theta}
\le 1-\frac12 k^2\sin^2 \theta
$.

Comment: can you explain how you were able to get those inequalities/boundaries?

Comment: Experience, and looking at the desired answer. Integrating 1 from 0 to $\pi/2$ gives $\pi/2$ and similarly for the lower bound.